# Structured XMLIndex giving error on creation

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, xmltype, xmlindex

I have a table having one columns as XMLTYPE being stored with Object-Relational storage. Below is table ddl.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders ( Order_id number not null,
                  Order_status Varchar2(100),
                  Order_desc XMLType not null )
                  XMLTYPE Order_desc STORE AS OBJECT RELATIONAL
                  XMLSCHEMA "http://localhost/public/xsd/Orderstore.xsd"
                  ELEMENT "OrderVal";
```

I have successfully registered the schema to load XSD with XML DB. Below is the XML being loaded into the XMLTYPE column.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<draftorders>
<OrderSumm>
   <Ordercod>OrderBookings</Ordercod>
</OrderSumm>
<Orderattrs>
 <Orderattr Ordername="HROrder">
    <OrderVals>
        <OrderVal>
             <listvalue>Order1</listvalue>
             <Orderattrs>
                  <Orderattr Ordername="Node1_Child1">
                     <OrderVals>
                         <OrderVal>
                              <listvalue><![CDATA[ Node1_Child1_OrderValue_1]]></listvalue>
                              <Orderattrs>
                                   <Orderattr Ordername="Node2_Child1">
                                        <OrderVals>
                                             <OrderVal>
                                                  <listvalue><![CDATA[ Node2_Child1_OrderValue_1]]></listvalue>
                                             </OrderVal>
                                        </OrderVals>
                                   </Orderattr>
                                   <Orderattr Ordername="Node2_Child2">
                                       <OrderVals>
                                            <OrderVal>
                                                  <listvalue><![CDATA[ Node2_Child2_OrderValue_1]]></listvalue>
                                            </OrderVal>
                                       </OrderVals>
                                   </Orderattr>
                              </Orderattrs>
                         </OrderVal>
                     </OrderVals>
                  </Orderattr>
             </Orderattrs>
        </OrderVal>
    </OrderVals>
 </Orderattr>
 </Orderattrs>
 </draftorders>
```

This XML contain around 2500 values for Node2 Orderattr. Am using the below query to print out all the Node2 values in one go using XMLTABLE.

```
SELECT ord.OrdName, ord.OrdVal
FROM Orders,  XMLTable('/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[1]/OrderVals/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr'
                     PASSING Order_desc
                     COLUMNS "OrdName"   VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '@Ordername',
                             "OrdVal"    VARCHAR2(4000) PATH  'OrderVals/OrderVal[1]/listvalue') ord;
```

Output:-

```
Node2_Child1
Node2_Child1_OrderValue_1
Node2_Child2
Node2_Child2_OrderValue_1
......
Node2_Child2500
Node2_Child2500_OrderValue_1
```

Now I want to restrict my resultset to only first 25 Node2 Orderattr values and not the entire set. How should I go about restricting the resultset to only first 25 node values.

Able to get it using XMLTable.

I have tried below XMLQuery function to achieve the same above output, but receive truncated output.

```
SELECT XMLQuery(            '/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[1]/OrderVals/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr/(@listname, OrderVals/OrderVal/listvalue/text())'
PASSING o.Order_desc RETURNING CONTENT)
FROM Orders o;
```

Output:-
          Node2_Child1Node2_Child1_OrderValue_1Node2_Child2Node2_Child2_OrderValue_1Node2_Child3Node2_Child3_OrderValue_1Node2_Child4Node2_Child4_OrderValue_1Node2_Child5Node2_Child5_OrderValue_1........Node2_Child25Node2_Child25_OrderValue_1

Thanks...

Comment: What is the "first 25?"  You need some sort order.  Then use ROWNUM to limit the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a condition with [`position()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-position) Xpath function to the end of a XQuery expression:

```
...
XMLTable(
  '/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[1]/OrderVals/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[position() <= 25]'
...
```

[<kbd>SQLFiddle test with your exapmle</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/16773)

**Update**

Question updated, so a little bit more about `XMLQuery()` function.
First of all, this function return single XMLType, therefore to get individual elements you need to use `ExtractValue()` function:

```
with params as (
  select XMLParse(content '
  <draftorders>
   <!-- EXAMPLE XML FROM QUESTION GOES HERE -->
 </draftorders>
  ')
  doc from dual
)
select 
  ExtractValue(xml_val, '/Orderattr/@Ordername') order_name,
  ExtractValue(xml_val, '/Orderattr/OrderVals/OrderVal[1]/listvalue') list_value
from (
  SELECT 
    XMLQuery(
      '//OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[1]/OrderVals/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[position() < 2]'
      PASSING doc returning content
    ) xml_val
  from 
    params
);
```

[<kbd>SQLFiddle test for XMLQuery variant</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/16839)

Second: if your XQuery return set of nodes then resulting XML not well-formed because there are no single root node.

Last: In your variant with XMLQuery expression returns set of values, not XML. All value sequences in XQuery concatenated without separators, so you got what you got:

```
Node2_Child1<![CDATA[ Node2_Child1_OrderValue_1]]>Node2_Child2<![CDATA[ Node2_Child2_OrderValue_1]]>
```

and after evaluation this expression translated to just

```
Node2_Child1Node2_Child1_OrderValue_1Node2_Child2Node2_Child2_OrderValue_1
```

Oops... You mistyped `@Ordername` and changed it to `@listname` at least in question text, so this part returns empty string and if this expression evaluated without changes result would be like

```
Node2_Child1_OrderValue_1Node2_Child2_OrderValue_1
```

Comment: Its working with position(). I am more inclined towards using XMLQuery to perform the same operation i.e. print say 25 node-child values.I have edited my question to list the XMLQuery I tried to achieve the same, but I get truncated output when I run the XMLQuery. Please advice.

Comment: @Sunny Please update also example XML in your question because your XQuery don't work with example you provided as well as XMLTable variant. Just look at top node in query (`/OrderVal`) and top node in example XML (`draftorders`).

Comment: With the XML query I provided above, I added position() to return 25 rows. But all the resultant rows are coming after another and not one row at a time. 
How can I get the output rows being printed one row at a time like we get it when I use XMLTable ??

Comment: Modified question to show the Output I am getting when running the XMLQuery (as given in my question)...

Comment: @Sunny Why don't use [XMLTable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm)? It acts exactly as [XMLQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions224.htm) from XQuery point of view, but [designed](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb_xquery.htm#sthref1705) exactly to return results "row by row" as you required. Just look at this thing: you `select` XQuery  `from` some table and you `select` some data `from` XMLTable ...